# Docker failing to find anaconda-client

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I'm very new to docker and am having a bug when trying to build a docked app. I have a python script that I want to wrap with docker. My requirements.txt file begins as such:

```
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.9.7
anaconda-project==0.8.3
asn1crypto==1.2.0
astroid==2.3.2
astropy==3.2.2
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.3.0
...
```

and my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./python_script.py
```

On running `docker build --tag python_app .`, I get the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.097GB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:alpine3.7
 ---> 00be2573e9f7
Step 2/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> 6f46c90dbc6f
Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 9458595eba85
Removing intermediate container 9458595eba85
 ---> 0f1fb57bba19
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 8eb7b6f86dff
Collecting alabaster==0.7.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ad/00b090d23a222943eb0eda509720a404f531a439e803f6538f35136cae9e/alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
You are using pip version 19.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Can I just drop anaconda-client from requirements.txt? I built the file just using pip freeze, and don't directly import it in the code, though I would like to keep the whole list if possible for simplicity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is no `anaconda-client==1.7.2` the last version is `1.2.2`

see [this](https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/)

I think you refer to this [conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-client):

then you need to use `conda` to install it and there is the version `1.7.2`

and I suggest you to use this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/)

Comment: But then why is it being returned from pip freeze?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I've generated the requirements.txt file by running pip freeze > requirements.txt. As I understand it, pip freeze should list what I have installed, which would imply that I have a version 1.7.2 of anaconda-client (or at least something that pip thinks is version 1.7.2)?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-client here lists version 1.7.2

Comment: I already updated the answer , that is not installed with pip

Answer (score 0):

I think python:anaconda-client and anaconda:anaconda-client No matching

https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda-client

so,try down version `pip install anaconda-client==1.2.2`, it's work